# JQuery Ajax File Upload insert User ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new here, hope you can help me out.
I am trying to upload an image using ajax(), it works now, but now I need to attach the user id, to the image or just save it inside the database to make it match to the user, I was thinking maybe changing the image file before uploading, but no luck so far, here is my code:

```
$('#avatar-upload').change(function(e){
    var id = $("input[name=id]").val();
    var file = this.files[0];
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('avatar-upload', file);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'upload.php',
        type : 'POST',
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        data : form,
        success : function(response) {
            $("#response").css({'display':'block'}).hide().html(response.html').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

I've got the code from here: [jquery ajax file upload](http://saravanan.tomrain.com/jquery-ajax-file-upload/)

Hope someone can help me out here
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also append your ID in your form:

```
$('#avatar-upload').change(function(e){
 var id = $("input[name=id]").val();
 var file = this.files[0];
 var form = new FormData();
 form.append('avatar-upload', file);
 form.append('uploaded-id', id); //Here is the appended ID
  $.ajax({
    url : 'upload.php',
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    data : form,
    success : function(response) {
         $("#response").css({'display':'block'}).hide().html(response.html).fadeIn(1000);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Aldrin for the quick response. No how can I be able to get this value form the php side? whould it be a post?

Comment: Yes. Hmm. Can you print_r($_POST) in your PHP?

Comment: I think this should be done with `$_FILES` because you're passing a image or videos.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you very much.
I used $file['name'] = $_POST['uploaded-id'].'.'.$extension;
Since in the PHP Code it exploded the extension, so just used it.
Thanks AGAIN!!!!!!

Comment: No problem glad to help.